# How can I work around this IE 11 behaviour where flexbox + inline-block + overflow causes overlap?

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have an IE11 bug which I'm looking to work around somehow.

My setup:

1. The is a `div` which I will call `outer` which has `display: flex`, `flex-direction: column`, and `width: 100%`.
2. It contains two other `div`s, which I will call `upper` and `lower`.
3. `upper` contains a number of `inline-block` elements – enough to require some wrapping.
4. `lower` contains enough other elements to overflow off the bottom of the screen, and so will get a scrollbar.

What I would expect to happen is that `upper` should be big enough to contain all of the `inline-block` elements inside it. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE11 it isn't tall enough.

This problem also occurs with `display: inline`, but not with `display: block` (although I think I definitely need `inline-block` for my layout).

If I reduce the amount of content inside `lower` so that it fits on the screen, the problem goes away.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.outer {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.upper {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: pink;
}

.upper div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10rem;
  max-width: 10rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.lower {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.lower p {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="upper">
    <div>0</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
    <div>16</div>
    <div>17</div>
    <div>18</div>
    <div>19</div>
  </div>

  <div class="lower">
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *4. `.inner` also contains enough other elements to overflow off the bottom of the screen.* ... If you mean the `p` elements, they aren't in `.inner`. They're in `.outer`.

Comment: Also note that the `height: 100%` on `.outer` is likely not to work in some browsers. You need to define a height on the parent for percentage height to work on the child. Use `height: 100vh` instead, or see here for a complete explanation on using percentage heights: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Comment: Thanks Michael_B, have corrected the text from inner to outer.

Adding html, body: 100% fixes the preview, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min-height` instead of `height` when you know that you'll receive overflow.

I've replaced `height: 100%` for `html`, `body` and `.outer` with `min-height: 100vh` only for `.outer` just for brevity.

Demo:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: pink;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.inner div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10rem;
  max-width: 10rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.outer p {
  background-color: green;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div>0</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
    <div>16</div>
    <div>17</div>
    <div>18</div>
    <div>19</div>
  </div>
  
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

If you need to add vertical scrollbar to your `.outer` when necessary just add `overflow-y: auto`. Demo:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: pink;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.inner div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10rem;
  max-width: 10rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.outer p {
  background-color: green;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div>0</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
    <div>16</div>
    <div>17</div>
    <div>18</div>
    <div>19</div>
  </div>
  
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

#### Update for new markup

Just add `flex-shrink: 0` for `.upper`. Demo:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.outer {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.upper {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: pink;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.upper div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10rem;
  max-width: 10rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.lower {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.lower p {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="upper">
    <div>0</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
    <div>16</div>
    <div>17</div>
    <div>18</div>
    <div>19</div>
  </div>

  <div class="lower">
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```